# Where exactly in the C++14 Standard does it allow the use of a user-defined conversion function in a direct-initialization?

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer

For example, in the snippet below the user-defined conversion function `C::operator A()` is implicitly invoked to convert an lvalue of type `C` into a prvalue of type `A`, which copy-initializes the variable `a` in a **direct-initialization**.

```
struct A {};  
struct C { operator A() { return A(); }; };

int main()
{
     C c;
     A a(c); 
}
```

I just want to know where this is described in the C++14 Standard. I have a feeling that the answer is in [over.match.copy]/1 bullet point (1.2), but I'm having a problem with the section title **Copy-initialization by user-defined conversion**.

Comment: I think that _copy-initialization by user-defined conversion_ refers to a constructor of the type `A(const C &)`, but that is not what your code uses. Your code just calls the copy constructor `A(const A&)` with an argument that happens to be the result of a user-defined conversion.

Comment: [over.match.ref]. You are actually converting `c` for binding to the copy constructor's parameter.

Comment: @rodrigo  That's exactly what I tried to describe in my question, i.e., the code is using the default copy-constructor to direct-initialize the variable `a` from `c`, using the conversion function `C::operator A()´.

Comment: @T.C. Then, what would you say about the presence of this sentence in [over.match.copy]/1 (1.2): `When initializing a temporary to be bound to the first parameter of a constructor where the parameter is of type “reference to possibly cv-qualified T” and the constructor is called with a single argument in the context of direct-initialization of an object of type “cv2 T”, explicit conversion functions are also considered.`

Comment: s/copy/move/ in my previous comment. But I suspect that there's a defect here.

Comment: @T.C. Let's assume you are right. Take a look at [this snippet](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b887e9ab708bd35). Which paragraph does allow for the calling of the user-defined function in this second example?

Comment: [over.match.copy]. You are copy-initializing the `D` parameter from `c`. You can read the standard as well as I do.

Comment: @T.C. I'm referring to the apparent contradiction between the section title **Copy initialization by user-defined conversion** and the fact that `A a(c);` is a **direct-initialization**.

Comment: It's direct-initialization for `a`. Not for the parameter of `A`'s constructor.

Answer (score 0):

There are two constructors on `A` that can be invoked with a single argument:

```
A(A const&); // copy constructor
A(A&& );     // move constructor
```

In either case, [[dcl.init.ref]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5.1.2) explains how we can initialize the reference:

> A reference of type "*cv1* `T1`" is initialized by an expression of type "*cv2* `T2`" as follows:
>   — If the reference is an lvalue reference and the initializer expression
>     — is an lvalue (but is not a bit-field), and “*cv1* `T1`” is reference-compatible with “*cv2* `T2`”, or
>     — **has a class type (i.e., `T2` is a class type), where `T1` is not reference-related to `T2`, and can be converted to an lvalue of type “*cv3* `T3`”, where “*cv1* `T1`” is reference-compatible with “*cv3* `T3`” (this conversion is selected by enumerating the applicable conversion functions ([over.match.ref]) and choosing the best one through overload resolution)**,
>     then the reference is bound to the initializer expression lvalue in the first case and to the lvalue result of the conversion in the second case (or, in either case, to the appropriate base class subobject of the object).

We have references of type `A` or `A const` being initialized by an expression of type `C`, which is a class type not reference-related to `A`. To check if it can be converted to a reference-compatible type *cv3* `T3`, we check [[over.match.ref]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.ref):

> The conversion functions of `S` and its base classes are considered. Those non-explicit conversion functions that are not hidden within `S` and yield type **“lvalue reference to *cv2* `T2`” (when initializing an lvalue reference or an rvalue reference to function)** or **“*cv2* `T2`” or “rvalue reference to *cv2* `T2`” (when initializing an rvalue reference or an lvalue reference to function)**, where “*cv1* `T`” is reference-compatible with “*cv2* `T2`”, are candidate functions. For direct-initialization, [...]

Hence, for the copy constructor, we consider those conversion functions that yield `A&` and for the move constructor, we consider those conversion functions that yield `A` or `A&&`. We don't have the former, but we do have the latter: `operator A()`.

This makes the move constructor of `A` a viable constructor, but not the copy constructor of `A`. Since we only have one viable candidate, it is trivially the best viable candidate.